# How to go back to previous view in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am a beginner in iOS programming and I want to implement the functionality of going back to home view.

I have use this code:

```
-(IBAction)onclickhome:(id)sender
{

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I have used navigationController in home button click event but it is not jump to home screen.

Do you have any suggestion and source code which applies to my code?

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

What do you mean with

> I have used navigationController in home button click event but it is
>   not jump to home screen

?

If you want to pop to the root controller you can use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated`.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

From Apple doc of `UINavigationController`

```
popToRootViewControllerAnimated:

Pops all the view controllers on the stack except the root view controller and updates the display.
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

If you have set up a `UINavigationController` and its root controller is called A, then if you navigate from A to B and then from B to C you have two possibilities to come back to a previous controller (you can have others but I list the main ones):

- navigate back from C to B with `popViewControllerAnimated`
- navigate back from C to A with `popToRootViewControllerAnimated`

Comment: Using your example, how could I jump back from D -> B ? Also the change in views should be done with a flip animation. Any ideas?

Comment: @taymless `popToViewController` is the choice. For references see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html.

Comment: yeah, I saw that, but how would I have to define that its going to be a flip animation? I would have tried `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:` since it allows to set the animation type, which would be `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight`.

Comment: @taymless The best way to get support is to open a new question for it. I haven't tried it already and I don't know how I could help you. Sorry.

Comment: ok. in case somebody is interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384493/jump-back-several-steps-in-navigation-tree-with-custom-animation

Answer (score 6):

The best way to navigate back and forth views is by pushing and popping views from navigation view controller stack.

To go one view back, use below code. This will ensure that the smooth transition between views are retained.

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = self.navigationController;
[navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

To go two views back, do as below

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = self.navigationController;
[navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If you aren't going back to your expected view, execute below code before popping any of the views...

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = self.navigationController;
NSLog(@"Views in hierarchy: %@", [navigationController viewControllers]);
```

You should see an array like the below one, which will help you in verifying the stack is maintained as expected.

```
Views in hierarchy: (
    "<Main_ViewController: 0x1769a3b0>",
    "<First_ViewController: 0x176a5610>",
    "<Second_ViewController: 0x176af180>"
```

Answer (score 4):

I use

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

since others answers didn't worked in Xcode 8.0