# Jump back several steps in navigation tree with custom animation

Tags: objective-c, animation

Follow up question on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392567/how-to-go-back-to-previous-view-in-objective-c)

Say my app has several `ViewControllers`, let's call them A,B,C,D. Usually moving back one step, i.e. from D -> C, would be using the back button in the `NavigationBar` or via code with the line

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

What I want to do is going back several steps, like from D -> B. This would be done with

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:B animated:YES];
```

Unfortunately this way I can't decide which animation to use. Instead of the default animation I have to use a Flip animation.

The only way to do this I found was this method

```
[self.navigationController transitionFromViewController:self.navigationController.presentedViewController toViewController:B duration:300 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:nil completion:nil];
```

Is this the only way to achieve this or can anyone suggest a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference from your comments....

" sounds right, but where would I define that it's supposed to be a flip animation? As far as I can see this still uses the default animation. – taymless "

you need to perform the animation means you use this block of code....

```
  -(void)animatefromView:(UIView*)fromView toBlock:(void (^)(void))block // note block may be any executable code...
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: 1];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:fromView cache:NO];
        block();
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
```

and the method call will be....

```
[self animatefromView:self.navigationController.view toBlock:^{ 
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:ani animated:NO];
                                                                    }];
```

i hope this will help you...

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the C view controller from the navigation stack so when it pops from D, it will go directly to view B

```
// Remove Controller C from Stack
NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.navigationController viewControllers]];
[controllers removeObject:C];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:controllers];
```

Then you can use `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` with the animation you want and it will pop back to view B

To do the actual flip animation when popping the view controller, you can use the animation code below

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"flip_animation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: sounds right, but where would I define that it's supposed to be a flip animation? As far as I can see this still uses the default animation.